# insert Row into jtable using AbstractTableModel with hibernate

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, jtable, abstracttablemodel

im developing an application and i'm trying to insert a new row into jtable 
i've followed [this tutorial](http://hiparrot.wordpress.com/2005/11/23/hibernate-results-into-jtable/) , the user can add/remove product information(row) through a form.the database & the table should be updated ,the remove function works well but i can't insert new row into the table .
Note:- when i close the app & run it again the table is updated 
and here's my code

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

Object[] values;
String[] columnNames;
private ArrayList productInfoList;

public TableModel() {
    super();
    Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
    Query q = session.createQuery("from Product");
    productInfoList = new ArrayList(q.list());

    session.close();
}

@Override
    public int getRowCount() {
   //return dataVec.size();
     return productInfoList.size();
}

@Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
    return 9;
}

@Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Product product = (Product) productInfoList.get(rowIndex);
        values = new Object[]{product.getProdectId(),
        product.getProductName(), product.getProductBuyingPrice(),
        product.getProductSalesPrice(), product.getCategory(), product.getBrand(), 
        product.getProductQuantity(), product.getProductMinQuantity(), product.getProductDescription()};

    return values[columnIndex];

}
@Override
    public String getColumnName(int column)
{
    columnNames=new String[]{"id","Product Name","Buy price","Sale price ","Category",
    "Brand","Quantatity","Min Quantatity","Description"};
    return columnNames[column];
}
public void removeRow(int rowIndex) {
    productInfoList.remove(rowIndex);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
}

public void insertRow(int rowIndex,Product everyRow) {
    productInfoList.add(rowIndex, everyRow);
    fireTableRowsInserted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
}
  }
```

this is the code that i try to insert row with

```
public void AddRow() {
    int position = jTable1.getRowCount() - 1;
    System.out.println(position); // test
    Product product = new Product();
    tablemodel.insertRow(position, product);

}
```

Please help me as i'm get tired of it :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TableModel` is storing a `Product` object in an ArrayList.

So, when you want to add a new row to the model you need to create a `new Product` object and add the `Product` to the ArrayList.

Also, you don't need to invoke table.repaint(), the insertRow(...) method is invoking the fireTableRowsInserted(...) method which will tell the table to repaint the row.

Comment: thanks for ur answer , but can u provide me with the code as i tried and nothing is happened :|

Comment: @MohNage7, It's two line of code, create the Product and add the Product to the ArrayList. Update your question to show your updated code. Maybe someone will be able to find the error.

Comment: I've updated it . and still don't know what's wrong :\

Comment: Why are you adding a Product object with no data? In your original code you were taking the data from some text fields. Well, now you need to take the data from the text fields and add the data to the Product object. If you don't get a new row displayed in the table then it means: 1) you didn't invoke the code 2) your reference to the TableModel is wrong. Maybe you defined the "tableModel" variable twice? Anyway I can't help anymore because your code is not complete and we don't know the context of how all the code is working together.

Comment: i did what u've said and still nothing happened. and i think it's not from the tableModel reference , it works well with the remove method 
Thanks bro for ur answers and ur time :)